# How to check if URL is blocked by my firewall

Tags: java, url, firewall, httpconnection

I am trying to check if the URL is accessible or not. I am using HttpURLConnection for it. This is now I am implementing it.

```
public static boolean isUrlAccessible(final String urlToValidate)
            throws WAGException {
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection huc = null;
        int responseCode = -1;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlToValidate);
            huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            huc.connect();
            responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
        } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()+" "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return false;
        } catch (final MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()+" "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return false;
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()+" "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()+" "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (huc != null) {
                huc.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return responseCode == 200;
    }
```

When the Internet is down it throws an UnknownHostException, I wanted to know how do I check if a fire wall is blocking a URL and thats why I get an exception and not because that the URL is not accessible. Also, I am just checking for response code 200 to make sure that the URL is accessible. Are there any other checks I need to perform?

Comment: Observation: If you're using Java 7+ you could use a multi-catch to cut down on the code duplication in each individual catch block.

Comment: that really depends on your firewall implementation. it could be a timeout (in case the firewall simply drops the packets), another form of ioexception if the firewall rejects them, or something higher level if you have some sort of filtering proxy. In this case it can return a 403, which is hard to distinguish from a regular response, unless you know what to look for.

Comment: @JnoK -  Thank you for the input. Did not think about that. I am going to treat each Exceptions in a differently later on so I guess I will have to have different catch blocks for different exceptions.

Comment: Ok I guess I will treat these exceptions in a generic way. Any inputs on status code checks? Do i only check for 200 or should I also consider 300s etc?

Comment: You cannot, in general, _reliably_ distinguish between "blocked by firewall" and "network error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the Internet is down it throws an UnknownHostException

No, it throws that when the *DNS* is down or the host isn't known to DNS.

> I wanted to know how do I check if a fire wall is blocking a URL

You will get a connect timeout. In rare cases with obsolete hardware you may get a connection refusal, but I haven't heard of that this century. But you will also get a connect timeout if the host is down.

> I am just checking for response code 200 to make sure that the URL is accessible. Are there any other checks I need to perform?

No. But URLs aren't blocked by firewalls. *Ports* are blocked by firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

The exception I have usually seen when a firewall is blocking the connection is "java.net.NoRouteToHostException". Try catching that and see if it helps.

Comment: Whether others see the same thing depends entirely on the firewall.

Comment: No it isn't. That's when your local host doesn't know how to get there, e.g. to a private IP address. Nothing to do with firewalls whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry what did I miss to deserve a down vote? I was going by the docs, see here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html, and since the OP had mentioned about firewall, I was indicating that this is the most common exception we would see if a firewall was blocking the connection?

Comment: The documentation appears to be wrong. Firewalls can't control source routing. You don't have any evidence that this is the most common symptom.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the answer is "it depends".
Our perimeter firewall for example does a redirect, because we want to show the user a custom screen.
In this case, I would try to look into the HTTP Status code (30x).

I think it's hard to write a generic function for something like this, you need to tailor this to your setting or make it very configurable.

Just make sure to remain as generic as possible.
If your code for example assumes a redirect to a specific URL, this will beak once the infrastructure changes (which happens more often than anticipated).